# How to fix "NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl" error while using javax.xml.soap library

Tags: android, soap

I am working on an android app that uses SOAP to send requests to a web service. The code works fine while testing using junit however while deploying the app on any device, it gives the error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.SOAPDocumentImpl`

I have tried adding this dependency to the build.grade file for the app `implementation 'com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:1.4.0'` which doesn't fix the problem.

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.soap/saaj-api' }
    maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple' }
    maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj/saaj-impl' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jkuber.gov.jkuberpayeeportal"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:1.3.5'
    implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:1.4.0'
    implementation ('junit:junit:4.12'){
        exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module:'hamcrest-core'
    }
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: How did you end up fixing this?

Comment: Had to use ksoap library to send SOAP requests.